# Pull images from twitter tweets

Tags: jquery, twitter

As the Title reads, I want something like this:

if the tweet contains a link to an image(yfrog) then make a `<img>` with that link in src="".

How can i do this?

-- Update --

Okey so what I've come up with so far is that i should make a function consisting "return this.replace", just like Chris Coyier did with links:

```
String.prototype.linkify = function() {
    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
        return m.link(m);
    }); 
};
```

But I can't find a way to write a proper function for my need.

Again, what i want: 
If the string contains a word (for example instagram) select whole "word" (in this case http://...) and put it in src="" at an `<img>` tag.

-- Update 2 --

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities

I've got a feeling that i can make use of that `media_url` variable. Can I achieve it through JSON, which I'm using now to get the tweet's text? `$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/username.json?count=10&callback=?' ... {`

Comment: what have you done so far to `try it`?

Comment: @MattiasAlfborger Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951538/retrieve-twitter-pictures-or-videos-when-using-an-specific-hashtag/10909027#10909027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If twitter supplies this information, you would have to set `include_entities=true`.

The real URLs are located in the entities `<urls>` section. Then you will have to get the compose the thumbnail url yourslef and add it in src.

Comment: Could you please write a snippet for that? I'm currently getting my tweets through JSON.

Comment: for what? For composing the thumb url? It's as simple as parsing the yfrog url, getting the key, and adding it to a thumb url (google for yfrog thumb url)

Comment: But if I'm not capable of doing that, it's quite hard. I'm quite a rookie!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull images from the twitter api by passing the right params. Here is an example:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/media_timeline.json?offset=0&count=100&score=true&is_event=false&filter=false&include_entities=true&user_id=18099844&callback=jsfunc

Further go to the twitter photogallery example: https://twitter.com/#!/F_i/media/slideshow?url=pic.twitter.com%2FbdeUOxcO

Look at the requests made in firebug.

From there it should help you refine the data if it should come from yfrog.