# retrieve twitter pictures or videos when using an specific hashtag

Tags: twitter

I'm looking to create a single page for a school event where basically I would like to display all the pictures of tweets with an specific hashtag, and if possible any youtube or vimeo video.

I'm been taking a look to the twitter API, however I cannot find an starting point, does anyone has any idea about to approach this?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this article helpful to grab pictures mentioned in a tweet via Twitter's JSONP feed for a specific search term or hashtag](http://www.queness.com/post/8881/create-a-twitter-feed-with-attached-images-from-media-entities).

This is the part of the feed for a single Tweet containing the media object that holds info about images -

```
"text": "#Photos on Twitter: taking flight http://t.co/qbJx26r",
"entities": {
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 76360760611180544,
      "id_str": "76360760611180544",
      "media_url": "http://p.twimg.com/AQ9JtQsCEAA7dEN.jpg",
      "media_url_https": "https://p.twimg.com/AQ9JtQsCEAA7dEN.jpg",
      "url": "http://t.co/qbJx26r",
      "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qbJx26r",
      "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/twitter/status/76360760606986241/photo/1",
      "sizes": {
        "large": {
          "w": 700,
          "resize": "fit",
          "h": 466
        },
        "medium": {
          "w": 600,
          "resize": "fit",
          "h": 399
        },
        "small": {
          "w": 340,
          "resize": "fit",
          "h": 226
        },
        "thumb": {
          "w": 150,
          "resize": "crop",
          "h": 150
        }
      },
      "type": "photo",
      "indices": [
        34,
        53
      ]
    }
  ],
  "urls": [
  ],
  "user_mentions": [
  ],
  "hashtags": [
  ]

}
```

There doesn't appear anything similar for videos but you can look into the "urls" array within "entities" to check for references to YouTube video links.

Comment: how can i get small image size?any idea?

Comment: There is a "video" type for media in the Twitter documentation currently however I am only getting "photo" even if the tweet contains a video.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a direct answer.

I recently did something similar with Instagram (displaying images based off hastags).

I used a jQuery plug in that was almost too easy to set up. You basically just fill in what hashtag you want, and the limit of photos to display in a simple function and it's good to go.

Perhaps there is something similar for twitter?

Best of luck.

Comment: could you share that plugin? I'd appreciate it :)!